# Can I change a frequency band of an EQ board?

Tags: pcb, band-pass, cutoff-frequency

Is it possible to change one of the frequency bands of this EQ board?

In particular, the low frequency adjuster is 100Hz and I want to make it 60ish Hz.

My understanding is that i need to meddle with the capacitors and resistors around the IC controlling that particular band, but is this the case?

I think the IC is 4558d but I can't really see from the photos.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you don't have the schematic you're going to have to reverse engineer it. If you do have the schematic then [edit] it into your post.

Comment: also, even iif you get the schematic: that's a redesign of all the analog components on there. Great, you're keeping the PCB. Is that really what you aim for? What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, those are probably 4558 dual op-amp IC's. Search for circuits online for graphic equalizers. Looks like the resistors for each stage are the same, so the frequency band is being set by the capacitors. Unfortunately, small surface-mount capacitors are not labeled with their values. You might be able to measure them in-circuit, but most likely you have to unsolder them to measure accurately, then replace with a larger capacitor value to move the frequency band down. Quite a bit of work and risk just to nudge that lower band down.

Comment: Just add an external 60 Hz boost/fade circuit and do the job properly.

Comment: also, you need to recalculate all your capacitors if you just want to change a single band - otherwise your equalize will have overlaid and deaf regions, and you usually don't want that. Seeing that you've let all this sit for an hour: Voting to close lacking further application detail allowing us to help you.

Comment: Thanks Mark, my thoughts as well. I asked the seller for a schematic but he hasnt got one. I do have a LC meter so i could measure the caps and try some slightly higher values. Problem is that without the schematic im left wondering why are there 4 caps around each IC and which ones do i need to change. Looking at most schematics with this IC on the web i can see only 2 caps per IC. Maybe there are some in series/parallel or something?